# Swift - Synchronous execution of large for loop without completion handlers

Tags: swift, asynchronous, synchronization

This is more of a theory question. If I have a large for loop, say

```
   var array = []
   let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
   for i in 0..<1000000000 {
       myGroup.enter()
       let x = i + 1
       let y = (x/2 * 15832) ^ 15
       array.append(x)
       array.append(y)
       myGroup.leave()
    }
    myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
       performOperationForArray(array:array)
    }
```

Will this ensure that all contents within the for loop get executed prior to `performOperationForArray`? Even though the calculations inside the loop don't have a completion handler for themselves?

Thanks.

Comment: You are entering and leaving the group before you enter it again. This will call the notify the number of times your loop is run.

Comment: If this is the case, is there a way to force the entire for loop to run prior to the `performOperationsForArray` function executes?

Comment: That is how a normal for loop works. What problem are you facing when you run a normal loop?

Comment: The loop doesn't finish executing before the following operation is run...that's literally the problem

Comment: Then you might be doing something other than the code that you posted inside your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the dispatch group. Just run the loop in the background. When the loop is done, call `performOperationForArray` on the main queue as needed.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
   var array = []
   for i in 0..<1000000000 {
       let x = i + 1
       let y = (x/2 * 15832) ^ 15
       array.append(x)
       array.append(y)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        performOperationForArray(array:array)
    }
}
```

Of course this assumes that your real code is not doing any asynchronous processing inside the loop.

Comment: Ah, you mean `DispatchQueue.global().async`?

Comment: Oops. Yes. I fixed that typo.

Comment: Will this enforce the contents of the large for loop be fully executed prior to running the main async thread?